# apex oracle:i am writing store procedures .what is the alernate of sp_OACreate and E_OAError?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

i am writing store procedures in apex oracle :
    can any one tells me about alternate of sql server in oracle

like

```
E_OAError = ?

sp_OACreate =?

sp_OAGetProperty =?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to work with COM objects, the closest equivalent would be the [Oracle COM Automation Feature](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b31223/ch2insta.htm). But if possible you should probably use .NET code instead, which is supported with the [Oracle Database Extensions for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085095.html); this is the equivalent of CLR support in SQL Server.

You haven't given any information about your operating system or Oracle version, so you will need to check for compatibility issues (e.g. per the documentation, the only server OS supported by COM Automation is Windows Server 2003).